# Premature end of script on VPS

Tags: php, apache, redhat

i have a VPS mounted with RedHat OS. Today, install DAV module for Apache from WHM and the services was restated.

Apache works fine, but PHP has troubles. All my php scripts return 501 Internal Server Error.

In the log `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` i can see:

> [error] [client 190.247.67.31] Premature end of script headers:
>   info.php

And PHP command line doesn't work. When i try `php -v` the command doesn't show the PHP version and nothing is returned.

Note: PHPMyAdmin works.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You will need to install `php-cli` for it to work on command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was an incorrect php.ini configuration.